# Retrieving values from WSDL before making a request

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

I'm very new to working with web services and I'm trying to understand the basics of it in Android using the ksoap2 library. Here's the question: [this](http://webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx?WSDL) is the WSDL file of a service I'm using. It's a service that converts values between different units. The units are stated in the WSDL. Now, is there any way to read those units and, say, populate a `Spinner` to let users choose the units they want to work with? A code solution will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use wsimport to generate stubs for the service interface and associated types, you should get a java WeightUnit enumeration.  The code solution would then utilize the values making up the enumeration to populate whatever control is appropriate.